# Webpage will not scroll down, it did then just quit

Tags: html

I have a website http://www.thecarnivalmidway.com/index.htm 200 pages and I have 1 that wont scroll, it use too. I've tried to figure it out and cant. so I am lost now, here is the link for the page that wont scroll http://www.thecarnivalmidway.com/site2/carnival_northeast.htm

Please help!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firebug tells me that on that page on line 105 you have a css instruction that says: `overflow: hidden`.
This means that what is not fitting the screen size is hidden. 
Remove that line and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS problem. This is the CSS applied to the body tag:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The `overflow: hidden;` should be removed:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```